# "sprintf" error in esp-idf. gcc version 9.1.0 in msys2

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, msys2, esp-idf

I was using msys2 earlier with gcc 6.4.0 and was working for my project. I upgraded the toolchain and gcc to 9.1.0. Now I am getting this error:

small part of code:

```
    memset(payload, 0, 8192);
    sprintf(payload, "GET %s%s HTTP/1.1\r\n", dynamic_fota_url, 
    new_firmware_version);
    sprintf(payload, "%sHost: %s\r\n", payload, dynamic_hostname);
    sprintf(payload, "%sPort: 443\r\n", payload);
    sprintf(payload, "%sAccept: */*\r\n\r\n", payload);
```

and error message is:-

```
D:/dozee/dozee_compiler/msys32/home/esp-idf/examples/dozee_fw_v62/main/dozee_next.c:2092:12: error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Werror=restrict]
    sprintf(payload, "%sPort: 443\r\n", payload);
            ^~~~~~~                     ~~~~~~~
D:/dozee/dozee_compiler/msys32/home/esp-idf/examples/dozee_fw_v62/main/dozee_next.c:2093:12: error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Werror=restrict]
    sprintf(payload, "%sAccept: */*\r\n\r\n", payload);
            ^~~~~~~                           ~~~~~~~
D:/dozee/dozee_compiler/msys32/home/esp-idf/examples/dozee_fw_v62/main/dozee_next.c:2344:15: error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Werror=restrict]
       sprintf(payload, "%sHost: %s\r\n", payload, dynamic_hostname);
               ^~~~~~~                    ~~~~~~~
D:/dozee/dozee_compiler/msys32/home/esp-idf/examples/dozee_fw_v62/main/dozee_next.c:2345:15: error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Werror=restrict]
       sprintf(payload, "%sPort: 443\r\n", payload);
```

How can I fix this. how can I downgrade my gcc to previous version?

Answer (score 2):

> error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3
>
> How to fix this one.

Do NOT alias argument 1 to printf with any other argument.

```
sprintf(some_buffer, "%s fmt string", some_different_buffer);
```

Aliasing the buffer is invalid and not allowed to do and results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). The buffers you write to and read from are not allowed to overlap.

Use `strcat` to append to string. Or calculate offset and append to buffer by shifting buffer starting position you use with `sprintf`. Prefer using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`. `snprintf` and `sprintf` return count of bytes written (excluding zero terminating byte), use that count. A typical usage of appending to buffer with `snprintf` may look like this:

```
char payload[200];
int len = snprintf(payload, sizeof(payload), "initialize");
len += snprintf(payload + len, sizeof(payload) - len, "Port: 443\r\n", payload);
len += snprintf(payload + len, sizeof(payload) - len, "Accept: */*\r\n\r\n", payload);
```

Comment: Is this added in latest gcc compiler for sprintf because when I was compiling with my old gcc it was working fine. BTW thanks for your suggestion and will try this implementation.

Comment: @MurlidharRoy It's been undefined behavior forever; it's just that gcc only started warning about it in recent versions.

Comment: @MurlidharRoy `it was working fine` is a perfect example of undefined behavior.

Comment: Why this isgiving this error- `error: '%d' directive writing between 1 and 3 bytes into a region of size 2 [-Werror=format-overflow=]
  sprintf(gain_str, "%d", live_gain-30);   3824:20: note: directive argument in the range [-30, 225] sprintf(gain_str, "%d", live_gain-30);
                    ^~~~3824:2: note: 'sprintf' output between 2 and 4 bytes into a destination of size 2
  sprintf(gain_str, "%d", live_gain-30);` Here char gain_str[2]={0} and unit8_t live_gain=0 initialised

Comment: Because `%d` `printf` format specifier will write between `1` and `3` bytes into a region of `2` bytes. It's right there in the description.